# Sql sum and show result in many column

Tags: sql

If I have a table look like [in this page](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp) and I wanna sum the orderPrice by each customer.
Then I wanna show the result show in one row look like [this](http://image.free.in.th/show.php?id=5babad1b3cfa1a024a7b42190a4847cd).
How can I write the query.

Ps. Sorry for show everything on web.

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not put any restrictions on how that information should be produced, you can do the following:

```
Select Sum( Case When Customer = 'Hansen' Then OrderPrice End ) As sumHansen
    , Sum( Case When Customer = 'Nilsen' Then OrderPrice End ) As sumNilsen
    , Sum( Case When Customer = 'Jensen' Then OrderPrice End ) As sumJensen
From CustomerTotals
```

Answer (score 0):

If your'e using SQL Server you can use [PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) statement.